# How to make function name dynamic within for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a javascript function name dynamic within for loop

I am doing like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var divlabel = "";
  var classlabel = "";
     for(index=1; index <=5;index++ ){
     divlabel = 'ShowHideDiv_'+index;
     classlabel = 'class_type_id'+index;
    function divlabel(classlabel) { 
    }
}
```

and function on select tag is that

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=5; $++){
<select id="class_type_id<?= $i;?>" name="class_type_id[]" class="browser-default" onchange="ShowHideDiv_<?= $i;?>(this);">
</select>
}?>
```

issue is that when I change a select option then this error is show on console window **Uncaught ReferenceError: ShowHideDiv_3 is not defined**
so I want that function is dynamic within for loop

Comment: Dynamic variable names are almost always a very bad idea. Consider another option, such as calling *one* function and checking the index of the element inside the function.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Read my "consider another option" sentence.

Comment: buddy i think you are confused in `option` and `select` because what is the meaning of putting select statement in `loop` with dynamic value which is need to be set on `option` tag of `select`

Comment: i think you want to use `option` value which is get by `onchnage` event so you have to set the `option` dynamically @Arslan

Comment: I am change this two things. function ShowHideDiv(classlabel) and onchange="ShowHideDiv()" but still show  the error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there is NO such thing as what you are doing here:

```
  var divlabel = "";
  var classlabel = "";
     for(index=1; index <=5;index++ ){
     divlabel = 'ShowHideDiv_'+index;
     classlabel = 'class_type_id'+index;

  function divlabel(classlabel) {}
```

There is no such thing as using strings to rename your named function, at least nothing normal and advisable. If anything, there's nothing good about renaming top level functions in any normal JavaScript code base.

Just use

```
function showHideDiv(){}
```

and reference that on your elements whatsoever

```
<select onchange="showHideDiv"></select>
<select onchange="showHideDiv"></select>
<select onchange="showHideDiv"></select>
<select onchange="showHideDiv"></select>
<select onchange="showHideDiv"></select>
<select onchange="showHideDiv"></select>
```

Comment: It *is* possible, it's just a very bad idea.

Comment: Edited to point out that it's a bad idea instead of impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create dynamic function using javascript. You have to create it using by json.

Comment: It *is* possible, it's just a very bad idea.

Comment: Using JSON? JSON doesn't implement functions.

Comment: @Teemu Probably meant putting function references on multiple JSON properties. Which is still a bad idea in this certain scenario but it's easier to implement.

Comment: @AbanaClara ?? Again, JSON doesn't implement functions, maybe Sandeep is talking about JS objects ..?

Comment: @Teemu Nah it's pretty easy. Something like `let n = 3; window["dynamicFunc"+n] = function(){ console.log("dynamic function"); }`

Comment: Oh yeah JS objects rather. Although you can write an entire function string inside JSON which is still basically possible. All you had to do is parse it to a JS object and eval the function string lol

Comment: @icecub Again: JSON is a textual data interchange format, it doesn't implement functions.

Comment: @AbanaClara Sure, but why to bother, you could write that string into a regular variable too, no need to mess with JSON.

Comment: Well right now we aren't talking about practicality. This entire post is extremely impractical. Somebody needs to give OP a lot better than he is asking for.

Comment: you have to make the dynamic function with in for loop so due to this reason it says function not defined. beacuse the function is not global.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, there are better solutions for your problem. However, for the purpose of learning, I think the only way to do this properly is by creating dynamic functions within its own scope:

```
// Create own scope
var dynFuncs = {};

(function(){
    "use strict";
    var name = "CustomFunc";

    // Custom Actions (define your function body here)
    function CustomAction ( id ) {
        var id = "This object has id: "+id;

        // Read only getter for id
        Object.defineProperty(this, "id", {get: function(){return id}})
    } 

    // Implement the new function
    var func = new Function("name", "action",
        " return function " + name + "(id){ "+
        // Prevent running in global scope
        " if(this === window) throw TypeError('Invalid constructor! try using new');" +
        " return Object.create(new action(id)); };"
    )(name, CustomAction);

    // Add function to the dynFuncs scope
    Object.defineProperty(dynFuncs, name, {value: func } )
})();

for(let i=0; i<=5; i++){
    dynFuncs["ShowHideDiv_"+i] = new dynFuncs.CustomFunc("ShowHideDiv_"+i);
}

// Call each function
dynFuncs.ShowHideDiv_0.id; // ShowHideDiv_0
dynFuncs.ShowHideDiv_1.id; // ShowHideDiv_1
dynFuncs.ShowHideDiv_2.id; // ShowHideDiv_2
dynFuncs.ShowHideDiv_3.id; // ShowHideDiv_3
dynFuncs.ShowHideDiv_4.id; // ShowHideDiv_4
dynFuncs.ShowHideDiv_5.id; // ShowHideDiv_5
```

Comment: I am tried with js ojects like this "let n = 3; window["dynamicFunc"+n] = function(){ console.log("dynamic function"); }" and this working

Comment: @Arslan Ye I know that works. I was the one who posted that. But just because you can, doesn't mean you should! At least what I've put above is more safe to use.

Comment: Thank u for supporting but if I am doing then resolve my problem and guide me, every one vote me in minus

Comment: @Arslan This is doing exactly what you're asking. It creates dynamic functions in a for loop. You're not asking anything else. You're not providing any other info. You're not explaining what the functions should do. So what else are you expecting from me? You're not giving me _anything else_ to work with.